# How to implement indicator for OptionMenuItem?

Tags: android, indicator, android-optionsmenu

I want to set indicator for OptionMenuItem like right image. Please help me
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image to the right is likely to be a [`TabHost`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) that provides these indicators out of the box.

If you want to use a [`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) instead you might want to look at the [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library.